Show that the group with this presentation has order $12$ and is isomorphic to the alternating group $A_4$

Show that the group $$G=\langle a, b, c; a^3, b^2, c^2, ab=ba^2, ac=ca, bc=cb\rangle$$has order $12$ and is isomorphic to the alternating group $A_4$.

I did manage to show that this group is of order $12$, however I'm struggling to find the right mapping to show isomorphism. I tried mapping $a$ to $(123)$, $b$ to $(12)(34)$ and $c$ to $(13)(24)$, but then $ac=ca$ is not satisfied and nor is $ab=ba^2$. The mappings of $b$ and $c$ are allright I think. Same thing happens in every other map for $a$. So, either my Cayley's table for $A_4$ is wrong or I'm missing something else here. Please help.

@Smiley1000 Thanks for reporting the mistake. Fixed. You could as well have suggested this correction in an edit (and when you'll have 2000 reputation, you will be able to edit other's posts like I did). Please delete your comment, and so will I.

I wonder why someone downvoted. This is an honest and interesting question, with true efforts.

This group has $\langle a \rangle$ as a normal subgroup, so it cannot be isomorphic to $A_4$. As Anne Bauval said, it is isomorphic to the dihedral group of order $12$.

This group of order $12$ is indeed not isomorphic to $A_4$ since in the latter, an element $a$ of order $3$ and an element $c$ of order $2$ cannot commute.
This group $S_3\times\Bbb Z_2$ is (isomorphic to) the dihedral group $D_{12}$.
It is not Magnus's Combinatorial Group Theory exercise (8 p. 21) which is erroneous, but your interpretation of it. He only asked to "show that [this group] has order $12$ and find a permutation group isomorphic to it". You discovered that such a permutation group cannot be isomorphic to $A_4$.
By Cayley's theorem, every group is isomorphic to some permutation group. Here, for instance, $G\cong S_3\times S_2\subset S_5$.

They do tho? Elements of order two in $A_4$ are (12)(34), (13)(24) and (14)(23) and they commute. The problem is that a (mapped to (123)) doesn't commute with c (mapped to (13)(24)).

Thank you, you are right! I fixed and completed my too hasty answer.
